# Pass a column (name and value) of a data.table to the function

Tags: r, function, data.table

I want to write a simple function to calculate the mean of Var1:

```
data<-structure(list(time = structure(c(1358832600, 1358832600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Var1 = c(0.4, 0.2)), .Names = c("time", 
"Var1"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

data<- data.table(data)

time                Var1
2013-01-22 09:30:00 0.4
2013-01-22 09:30:00 0.2

Aggregated.Data<- function(data, col) {
 aggregated <- ddply(data, time, summarise, col= mean(eval(col)))
 return(aggregated)
}

aggregated.data <- Aggregated.Data(data, quote(Var1))
Everything works, output:

time           Col
2013-01-22 09:30:00 0.3
```

Questions:

1. Is this the right way? I mean using quote and eval?
2. Why the second column name in output is col, How can I change it to Var1?

**Edit: Using data.table**

```
Aggregated.Data<- function(data, col) {
 aggregated <- data(data, list(col=mean(eval(substitute(col)))), by=list(time=time))
 return(aggregated)
}
```

Comment: If you are using a `data.table`, why not use `data.table` methods?

Comment: @akrun, I am actually using `data.table` methods, but I end up with the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps `f1 <- function(dat, col){
 DT <- dat[, mean(.SD[[1]]), time, .SDcols=col];
 setnames(DT, 2, col);
 DT 
 }` Or you can use `DT <- dat[, mean(dat[[col]]), time]`

Comment: Have you tried the function `f1` i.e. `f1(data, 'Var1')`

Comment: Yes, it worked. I see the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use `eval(as.name)` and get the `mean`.  We can change the column names later with `setnames`.

```
f1 <- function(dat, col){
 DT <- dat[, mean(eval(as.name(col))), time]
 v1 <- setdiff(colnames(DT), colnames(dat))
 setnames(DT, v1, col)
 DT 
}


f1(data, 'Var1')
#                  time Var1
#1: 2013-01-22 00:30:00  0.3
```

Comment: Those two options look different. Because you are doing a by-group operation, your first option looks at `col` within group, while the second option looks at `dat[[col]]` which is clearly not split up by group, right? Also, in my opinion, passing the `by` arg by position is rather obscure.

Comment: @Frank I didn't test it properly.  Thanks for the input.  Removed the second option.

Answer (score -2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

summarize_column = function(data, variable_name)
  data %>% 
    group_by(time) %>% 
    select_(lazy(variable_name)) %>% 
    summarize_each(funs(mean))

data %>% summarize_column(Var1)
```

Comment: This is another way, the problem is when you send the data.table to the function.

Comment: the question was about passing a column [name, value] of a data.table to a function.